# "Hundred-thousands" or "Hundreds of thousands"?

Tags: grammaticality, numbers

Which word choice is correct?

> The company saved several hundred-thousands of dollars.

or

> The company saved several hundreds of thousands of dollars.

I apologize. I did no prior research other than 4 years of scholars level English in college. I did not ask Google or Bing before asking an English language enthusiast group because I work in IT and have an ample grasp on a computer's natural language processing abilities.

Comment: Which did your independent research suggest is correct? I'd be very interested in hearing about what you discovered before you came to ask us.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of the site is that you articulate in full the context of the problem; another is that you have attempted some initial research on your own. What causes you to think that one or the other is or isn't correct? How many results for each phrasing turn up in a simple web search? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: By the way when a question is put on hold, it doesn't mean the question is "dead", it's a good opportunity for the asker to improve/fix/clarify his or her question. All you need is five users to cast their vote to reopen and voilà,  it's open again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both can be heard and used, but if you're writing them, *hundred-thousands* doesn't have a hyphen.

- **one/two/seven *hundred thousand* dollars**
  Shows an exact amount; often used in the context of money though can equally be used to count other things: *There are a hundred thousand posts on this site.*
- **hundreds of thousands of balls**
  Often used to convey the sense of *a lot*, rather than an exact number. It's a ballpark estimate of the number of things you're looking at.

---

In the case of your example, neither *feels* correct (though I'm unsure of technical correctness). I'd use something like

> The company saved several hundred thousand dollars.

or

> The company saved hundreds of thousands of dollars.